# Can't create Meteor.js helper based on parse.com query

Tags: javascript, meteor, parse-platform, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

My meteor app accesses Parse.com to pull in and display data. 
I started out integrating the parse.com javascript query directly into the template's rendered function, which worked well.

Now, I want to use the Parse.com query in a helper to pass it over to a meteor {{#each}} loop which lives in my template.

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
app: function () {
    //init new array
    var appsArr = [];
    //Create a Parse Query for Post objects
    var query = new Parse.Query("Apps");
    query.descending("createdAt");
    var appsObj = {};
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            // Add the returned Parse.Object values to appsArr
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                appsObj = {};
                appsObj.obid = results[i].id;
                appsObj.title = results[i].attributes.title;
                appsObj.screenshot1 = results[i].attributes.screenshot1._url;
                appsObj.appIcon = results[i].attributes.appIcon._url;
                appsArr.push(appsObj);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });

    return appsArr
}
});
```

Every time I try and return my array (appsArr) in the helper I get the error :
"Exception in template helper: undefined". I also can't get my parse objects to output in the console. Again, the same code works in the rendered function.

I am fairly new to Meteor.js and Blaze templates. please help me implement this parse query into the helper correctly so I can {{#each}} in the template.

```
 {{#each app}}
        <h3 class="app-title">{{title}}</h3>
{{/each}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with parse.com but I think its function is asynchronous and take the callback. So in this case, it is possible that 'appsArr' and 'appsObj' are not recognize within the 'query:success callback'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `query.find` function is asynchronous and non-blocking, you can't just assign variables in the callback and return them outside of the callback -- the callback hasn't run by the time you hit the `return` statement, so you're returning something that hasn't been defined.

An easy way around this will be to use a reactive variable (a variable whose assignment is watched); you can either use `[ReactiveVar][1]` or the built-in reactive `[Session][2]` variable.  I typically use `Session`.  A possible implementation would be something like this (apologies for not testing this out ahead of time):

```
Template.dashboard.onRendered({ // onRendered, calculate appVar
  Session.set('appsVar', null); // reset appsVar immediately -- can also do this in onCreated / onDestroyed to clean up
  //init new array
  var appsArr = [];
  //Create a Parse Query for Post objects
  var query = new Parse.Query("Apps");
  query.descending("createdAt");
  var appsObj = {};
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        // Add the returned Parse.Object values to appsArr
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            appsObj = {};
            appsObj.obid = results[i].id;
            appsObj.title = results[i].attributes.title;
            appsObj.screenshot1 = results[i].attributes.screenshot1._url;
            appsObj.appIcon = results[i].attributes.appIcon._url;
            appsArr.push(appsObj);
        }

        Session.set('appsVar', appsVar);
      },
      error: function(error) {
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  }
});

Template.dashboard.helpers({
  app: function() { return Session.get('appsVar'); } // This will re-run when Session.appsVar is updated in the callback above.
});
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! Set up the session Var and everything is working perfectly. Your code had some syntax errors but was able to just implement :
     Session.set('appsVar', null);
and 
 Session.set('appsVar', appsVar);

then your helper function :
    Template.dashboard.helpers({
  app: function() { return Session.get('appsVar'); } // This will re-run when Session.appsVar is updated in the callback above.
});